# jquery show html from different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr

I need some light here, i'm new to jquery and i'm trying to create a div to show the inner text of other div below, i'm not sure if i'm using the best approach and everytime i try to create a variable it won't work : (

here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vrtbyej0/

and the code i'm using

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.info-text').each(function() {
    $(this).after($('<div />', {
      class: $(this).attr('data-info'),
      text: ""
    }));
  });

$("div[class=" + $(".foot").attr("data-info") + "]").append($(".foot").html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="info-text" data-info="money"> money</div>
<div class="info-text" data-info="life"> life</div>
<div class="info-text" data-info="square"> square</div>
<div class="info-text"> option</div>
<div class="info-text" data-info="money"> money</div>

<div class="foot" data-info="money"> information</div>
<div class="foot" data-info="life"> red</div>
```

Comment: Where is  the code to create the <div>? What can't you get?

Comment: A part of your code is not in `document.ready` which means it will execute before the rest

Comment: One issue is that you are using `$(".foot").html()` and there are two spans with `class="foot"`.  That is ok but it means that `$(".foot")` returns an array of jQuery objects but when you do things like `.html()` or `.attr(...)` it is going to default to the first element in the array.

Comment: @nurdyguy now I understand the problem, thank you!. Do you know if there's a way to make it work for all the elements?

Comment: Do you want to put all of the data from both divs?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? can you show us an example?

Comment: @nurdyguy yes, I need it to show the information like this, of all the .foot elements http://i.imgur.com/ewocPpu.jpg

Comment: @Adjit I need it to show the information like this, of all the .foot elements http://i.imgur.com/ewocPpu.jpg

Comment: I added a solution which puts all of the `.foot` html into one string.  Is that what you want or are you trying to match the `.foot` html to a `.info-text` using the `data-info` value?

Comment: @nurdyguy I'm trying to match the using the data-info like you said, separately

Comment: K I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple divs with `class="foot"` which is fine but when you use jQuery `$('.foot')` it returns an array of jQuery objects.  This is still ok until you do `$('.foot').html()` because that is going to default to giving you the html of only the *first* element from the array.  If you want to get *all* of them then you need to set up a loop.

```
var html = "";
$('.foot').each(function()
{
    html+= $(this).html();
});
console.log(html);
```

You can see from the `console.log` that the `html` variable now has all of the html from the different elements so you can use that variable however you like.

EDIT:
Now I understand that you want to match the elements up by the data value so here is how you do that:

```
$('.foot').each(function()
{
    $('.info-text[data-info=' + $(this).data('info') + ']').append($(this).html());
});
```